# Scale all items (including text) on the HTML page in proportion to the size of the window

Tags: html, css, window, font-size

[On this page,](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107533178/Brochure/Home.html) notice how everything is the wrong size when the window is dragged around.

I want the "iframe" to keep a ratio of 1.778 (640*360, 1280*720, etc.) when scaled up or down. (When the user drags the window out, make it bigger. When the user drags the window in, make it smaller in proportion.)

I want the "border" surrounding the page to always be 8px by 8px. (The problem with using margin is that the window increases in size and the user has to scroll. - For my purposes I don't want this to happen.)

Lastly, the text needs to size up and down with the window. (Currently I am using a '%' to achieve this, [but apparently](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) '%' in the context of font-size means "Sets the **font-size** to a percentage of the **parent element's font size**." So i'll need a different approach here.)

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? Why was I voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a resize event to the window with jquery and make appropriate changes to the elements you want to rescale:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var currentwidth = $(this).css('width'); //just one way to get the window width
    var scaledwidth = parseInt(currentwidth) * 0.75; //calculate a new width
    $('#iframeId').css('width', scaledwidth); //one way to set an element's width (iframe in this case)

/* Do your other element re-sizing here. */
}
```

The line `var scaledwidth = parseInt(currentwidth) * 0.75;` uses `parseInt` to strip the 'px' from currentwidth.

Comment: Hi @Justin Gingy McDonald, "Notice I left out the specific math you need to calculate the sizes to maintain 1.7 scale.", no problem. Can I have that code in pure js?

Comment: And what about fonts? How do I say "font-size = 50% of the window size." What you've said there is: "Your iframe's width is equal to the window's width", not: "Your iframe's width is equal to 75% of the window's width." (Which would have been the answer to the question.)

Comment: One last thing. Instead of saying "Window.resize", can I say "div.resize"?

Comment: i have made some changes to my answer, and it is better to use jquery.
you can bind a resize event to any element, but your solution should only need to throw events when the window is resized.

Comment: Thank you, Justin :) I prefer this method. Thank you andrei as well that was an interesting article and I will be using some of that too, +1 to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

If you are only concerned with the element sizes, set the size of body element to width: 100%; and set size of all children elements in percentages instead of pixels. Then you have to do nothing: your layout will change automatically on screens of different sizes.

Alternatively, if you only support modern browsers (i.e. on phones and tablets), you can use a simple CSS3 line: transform: scale(). Then you can create your iFrame (or other object) in the dimensions you need, and scale it up or down as necessary.

See
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Alternatively, you can specify all font sizes, elements sizes, paddings and margins in ems or rems. Then you only need to change your em or rem base, and all elements will scale accordingly.

To use scale(), ems or rems, you have two options:

(1) JavaScript: Attach a resize listener to your Window object to set the property of the body element when a screen size changes.

(2) Use different CSS files for different screen sizes. The only difference will be in the body element rules. See:
http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: Hi @Andrea, I think I see where you're getting at, but I don't understand how to use "scale" to scale them according to the size of the window. Is there a js command for that? Like: "object.style.scaleX = 50% of the window's height."?

Comment: Also, is "scale" independent of height? Are you saying I can use "scale" instead of height and width?

Comment: Scale only works with the width and height. It allows you to create a layout for a specific width/height, and then change a single line (scale) instead of changing sizes of all elements and fonts for a new width/height.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the great tips!